# localStorage clears while navigating to next page?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, ng-storage

I store values to the localStorage using ng-storage plugin in angular.js.
while navigating to the next page the localstorage get cleared.

in html of the navigated page i have set base hfer

the fact is that,the code works fine when am working on an ip
when it is moved to a domain name it fails

any solution ??

Comment: Are you sure it gets cleared, or never gets set.. Any errors in console?..  In chrome you can see the state of localstorage in developer mode, under application tab.

Comment: yes it get cleared and i didn't get any errors in console

Comment: i manualy add an entry to the localstorage using browser console . But i was not able to see that value navigating back to the start page ,it was not there

Comment: Localstorage contents are sandboxed on domain basis so if you store have some data in localstorage on page *www.hello.mydomain.com* and move to *www.hola.mydomain.com* your content wont be visible it would be empty hit back and once again your data is visible

Comment: @Novice i have routed the pagein .htacess nd my  url of page is like  www.domain.com/value ie , www.domain.com to www.domain.com/value

Comment: Then check the ports maybe , data set on www.example.com:8080 cannot be read when user is on www.example.com. Same applies on http and https

Comment: i found out the issue, the redirected page url was example.com instead of www.example.com